# AWS NameError on Rails 3.2.11 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, aws-sdk

My Rails 3.2.11 app can't seem to find the AmazonS3 class below in production.  I can call it in a rails console with something like AmazonS3.create(), but for some reason when I call it in PdfGen.create_pdf (which in turn is called from a Rails controller during a request), I get the bellow NameError.

**Error I keep getting**

Job PdfGen.create_pdf (id=XX) FAILED (5 prior attempts) with NameError: uninitialized constant AmazonS3::AWS

**config/application.rb**

```
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib})
  config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]  # include all subdirectories
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
aws-sdk (1.60.1)
      aws-sdk-v1 (= 1.60.1)
    aws-sdk-v1 (1.60.1)
```

**lib/amazon_s3.rb**

```
class AmazonS3
  def self.signed_url(s3_key)
    s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => S3Config.access_key_id, :secret_access_key => S3Config.secret_access_key)
    bucket = s3.buckets[S3Config.bucket]
    bucket.objects[s3_key].url_for(:read, :expires => EXPIRES_IN_YEAR_2036)
  end
end
```

**lib/pdf_gen.rb**

```
class PdfGen
  def self.create_pdf
    ##some code to generate a pdf

    AmazonS3.create(amazon_s3_key, response.body)  #store on S3 bucket
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was an issue with the gem itself.  I added:

```
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
```

to the Gemfile instead of *aws-sdk* and it worked.